# Kendo export to excel is failing because of Buffer problem

Tags: excel, angular, kendo-grid

I'm working with kendo grid and I needed to export the data to excel
it keeps throw this error 
ERROR TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function

I replaced my code and data with the one in this sample:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-excel-export

but the excel file is not been downloading. and still getting error about buffering.
Any idea about my problem?

Comment: https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/196

Comment: @MuhammadAftab thanks but this in back-end code. how I would solve something in jsZip.js file?! I dnt have access to that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import the ExcelModule